# How to make automated tests popular?

Tags: testing, integration-tests

Our code base is growing for 20 years now. We are about 10 devs + sqa working with 500kloc. Some time ago a small team of us (2 devs, one from sqa) started working on an automated test program. Currently one run takes 11h and is somehow an integration test. We are working on it to get this down and reduce false positives and are making good progress in that. But details shouldn't matter.

It is working okay and we continue to improve it. We (the small team) like it very much. If we break something, we notice a day later and not 2 months later when sqa takes a look. Also, our managers (dev + sqa) like the idea. But other people in the team just ignore the testresults. In their mind, if tests are failing after a checkin, it's a problem of the test and not of the code change and it's just our toy project. We had discussions several times if a failing test is a real error. Most times it is.

We can't and don't want to enforce something. How can we show that automated testing is a thing?

Comment: This isn't a Software Engineering problem; it is a people problem.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I got downvotes on SO because "opinion based" and a comment that this site would suit perfectly (and upvotes on that comment). So: where should I ask? Educate me.

Comment: You could try [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/), but **read their [Help Center](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first.**

Comment: I am with @RobertHarvey about this being a people problem.  But as per Workplace, your question will probably we considered a dupe.  For example see this question which is fundamentally what you are asking https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/44964/how-to-introduce-better-software-development-practices-processes-to-the-workplac

Comment: @PeterM : I completely agree with the people-aspect. It's not a technical problem. Maybe I'm just "spoiled" by the good old times where everything programing related could go to SO when you have googled before :/ is there a flow-chart anywhere where to ask what without knowing the intent of every single SE-site? thanks for the link, looks like a good place to start. I'll delete the question here in a few hours.

Comment: If you can come up with a working flow chart that lists appropriate types of questions for each stack site, and also takes into account the vagaries of the group think of each different site .. then more power to you!

Comment: Do you know the 3 main arguments against change? "We never did it this way", "We always did it this way", "What kind of smartass are you?"

Comment: @DocBrown yes I do. I'm German. We invented it ;)

Comment: Do not let those downvoters (or even close-votes) discourage you! Some people may understand that such questions are important, and perhaps can provide help. By the way, also my colleagues fail to see the usefulness of automated tests, despite the previous version (without any automated tests) is a box of bugs. Just change one thing, and break a few other, seemingly unrelated things. Some people just do not want to learn (there is open resistance against learning new things).

Comment: @RobertHarvey depends on how much your devs like using their automated test tools...

Comment: It's a shame this question has been closed. If software engineering means anything it means the problems of working with actual people, and the answers to such problems will involve opinion. That said, a couple of quick ideas: (1) if you tests give false negatives, this will definitely increase pushback because the results will feel like a waste of time; (2) bring the runtime down, if at all possible. 11 hours doesn't feel immediate, even if it's far better than two months; (3) will sqa adopt these tests as metrics they watch. they're already recognized by your org in this area.

Comment: @DaleHagglund 100% agreed. I regret asking on SE almost every time for ~4 years now. A comment about this in this question had been deleted. I make good progress on (1) and (2): test time halved with a second node (more to come) and tests now run in a more reliable environement), (3) is more difficult/ frustrating but we will get there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Disclaimer**

Though I may sound like a manager, I wrote this as a developer who also needed to be persuaded that automated tests are good.

---

You must understand the basic psychology of developers. It is an ingrained need of developers to commit code. Anything that prevents them from doing so is a very, very bad thing. Failed test is definitely something that prevents them from doing so, ergo it is a bad thing. Hence the resistance.

What you must point out is that, while the automated tests slow them down short-term, in the long run it will save them a lot of grief and will actually speed them up, because they will be able to focus more on the development of new things, and will lose less time doing the other thing that developers hate to do: fixing bugs.

And yes, you must enforce it. You must get the unconditional support from the management and make writing automated tests mandatory and non-negotiable. Over time, the developers will get used to them. What will help is if you can devise some metrics that will show how much more new development was done, and by how much the number of bugs was reduced since you introduced the automatic tests. Words are volatile. Numbers are solid. And numbers are something an average developer understands better than words. If you can prove using solid numbers that automated tests are good, you will get little to no resistance to them.

Answer (score 11):

> In their mind, if tests are failing after a checkin, it's a problem
>   of the test and not of the code change and it's just our toy project.
>   We had discussions several times if a failing test is a real error.
>   **Most times it is.**

There's your problem.  If your tests are flaky (even if they are reliable 'most of the time'), then people will tend to ignore the results.  Your automation team should focus on eliminating those false negatives.  Only then will the rest of the team gain enough confidence in the results to actually trust them.

Comment: Then again, it could be something else.  Like resistance to change.  If a test fails, *there is always something to fix,* either the code or the test, so the attitude that people will ignore tests because the tests are flaky is misplaced.

Comment: We talked to them when we were sure that something broke (e.g. Test failed 3 times in a row after his checkin affecting the functionality in question). But yes, increasing reliability is the current priority.

Comment: @PeterSchneider a test can fail 100 times in a row, it will do that especially if the test is wrong.

Comment: On the other hand, a test that never fails is most likely completely useless

Comment: +1 Brittle tests are definitely a problem. Developers must be convinced the tests they write are useful, do not introduce needless complications, and *are not busywork*.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I do not see how 'resistance' would be the issue if tests actually point to bugs in the code. However, I do understand how resistance can be an issue if tests fail and do not directly point to something. A test should help you find the issue, not just state there is an issue somewhere in the 500.000 lines codebase. In that case, I would understand the reaction of the developer that there are always bugs in code. If an integration test of 11 hours fails, and all it says is that it failed, I would understand why developers do not want to use it.

Comment: @NickL: Um, nobody here is asserting that the problem is insufficiently-specific unit tests or inadequate error messages.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well if developers feel that test fail because of the test, and not because of the change, then I would expect that either a) the test _is_ flaky or b) the test _seems_ flaky. The latter is caused by insufficiently-specific unit tests or inadequate error messages, right? Or indeed, if every change implies that tests also have to change (e.g. due to volatile requirements). In this case, the test may even be to specific?

Comment: @NickL: Code is code, whether it's in a test or in an application.  Professional developers treat it as such, and don't point fingers or make excuses just because the failing code happens to be in a test.

Comment: @RobertHarvey While in theory, you may be right that code is code, it is not true that professional developers treat test code the same as normal code. Maybe they should, but testing is a whole domain on itself, with its own practices, tools, and techniques. Test code can be much more complex and verbose than 'normal' code, and when done wrong can cause significant and even unnecessary maintenance overhead.

Answer (score 6):

> We can't and don't want to enforce something.

You definitely should enforce it! If someone pushes new code and the tests fail the code should be rejected! It is the only way to reliably maintain a larger software project.

Comment: I guess that depends on the system, the tests, the scale, and the development process. Not all bugs can be resolved right away, nor do all issues have to be resolved right away.